# Streaming int as text into a file without creating string objects

Tags: c#, memory-management, garbage-collection

I'm streaming some text into a file. The following code is an MCVE to demonstrate the issue:

```
using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(@"d:\test.txt"))
{
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20000000; i++)
        {
            streamWriter.Write("Just ");
            streamWriter.Write(i);
            streamWriter.Write(" example.\r\n");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, it does not only stream strings into a file but also ints.

Unfortunately, the `Write(int)` method seems to call `ToString()` on the numbers, so above code creates 20M string objects. This can be proven with a memory profiler like dotMemory. These strings will be garbage collected, but they cause a 577 MB throughput on the garbage collector.

Is there a way to directly stream the ints (in a human readable format, not binary) into the file without creating temporary strings?

Comment: Well... the integer needs to be transformed to a text representation, so a call to `ToString()` will have to happen _somewhere_. You could possibly use a `char[]` lookup to write each character of the integer directly to the stream instead.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211162/how-to-convert-int-to-char-without-generating-garbage-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

You can do it one digit at a time using recursion:

```
void writeInt(StreamWriter w, int i)
{
    if (i<0)
    {
        w.Write('-');
        writeInt(w, -i);
    }
    else if (i>=10)
    {
        writeInt(w, i/10); // Write all but the last digit
        w.Write((char)('0' + i%10)); // Write the last digit
    }
    else
    {
        w.Write((char)('0' + i)); // Write single digit number
    }
}
```

Call it like this for a given integer:

```
int i = 42;
streamWriter.Write("Just ");
writeInt(streamWriter, i);
streamWriter.Write(" example.\r\n");
```